# Angular js - Digest Loop

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-digest

I may trying to clear my concept on digest loop. I have a small HTML page as :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>        
        <title>Practice</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="myController">
            Enter your text <br>
            <textarea rows="5" id="comments" ng-model="commentText"></textarea>
            <br>
            Type Char:{{ lenghtComment }}            
        </div>        
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="prac.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

=====================================
And small angualr file as :

```
var myApp=angular.module("myApp",[]);
myApp.controller("myController",["$scope",function($scope){
    $scope.commentText="";
   /* $scope.lenghtComment=function(){
        return $scope.commentText.length;
    };*/

 $scope.lengthComment=$scope.commentText.length;

}]);
```

I want to display the count of characters I type in the Text box. Though there are many ways to do so, I wanted to know why the above one does not work. Scope Variable "LenghtComment" is dependent on "commentText", so the digest loops detects a change on "commentText" as the user types in and should then reiterate over watcher-list to ensure if any dependent variable has changed. In this run it should find the change in "lenghtComment" variable and update the app.  But the case is not. However if I use the function as commented, it works perfectly great. Please point out gap in my understanding. Thanking you guys in advance.

Comment: is that a typo you have? in your HTML you have `lenghtComment` but in your JS file you have the correct spelling `lengthComment`.  Is it wrong in your code or just in your question body?

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the typo in your code, this won't work the way it is written now.

Angular doesn't continually re-run your controller every `$digest` cycle.  Instead, it creates listeners which monitor changes in the variables, and updates these variables.

However, in this situation, `$scope.lengthComment` isn't changing every `$digest` cycle.  It may appear to be changing, but in reality, `$scope.commentText.length` is an assignment that returns an integer (in this case, `0`).  Once the assignment is complete, it is not re-evaluated.  `lengthComment` is in this case a primitive, and it **is not** dependent on `commentText`.

In contrast, the other form `$scope.lengthComment=function()` *is* constantly changing.  The variable in this case isn't assigned to the **return value** of the function, but the **function itself**.  Every `$digest`, this function must be re-evaluated to determine if it's result is the same.

Comment: Thanks Claies. It clarifies my doubt. Thanks a lot. Also apologies for the typo.

Comment: typos happen, I just wanted to be clear that the typo wasn't the cause of the issue you were trying to solve.  If this answer sufficiently answered your question, then be sure to accept the answer. :)